# Returning Java child in a method

Tags: java

Given the following classes, I'm deciding on creating child classes based on an if/else statement, is this the right approach? Also, is it correct to declare a method that returns Parent and then return a child? (see someMethod). It doesn't seem right, is there a better way to do this?

```
public class Parent {

    int someInt;
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {

    int id1;
    String field1;
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {

    int id2;
    String field2;
}
```

The classes are used in the following way:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public Parent someMethod(int option) {

         Parent object = null;
         if (option == 1) { 
            object = new Child1();
            // set Child1 fields
            return object;
         }
         else {
             object = new Child2();
            // set Child2 fields
            return object;
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *is it correct to declare a method that returns Parent and then return a child?*

Yes, `Parent` would be the correct return type for this method. And the code looks ok.

A few minor remarks:

- You could implement it as `return option == 1 ? new Child1() : new Child2();`
- Classes don't really have "parent / child" relationships. Think *is a*. (Would you say a child *is a* parent?) Base class (or super class) vs subclass are better terms imo.

Comment: Your second "minor" remarks is not minor at all! It is the root concept of object inheritance. So it is really important to understand this to play with object oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is totally correct.

It is exactly what the factory design pattern looks like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: @aioobe as you are right about name, i disagree about must-be-a static thing or part of parent class

Comment: @aioobe This is an implementation choice. You are right that a lot of implementations make the factory methods static but IMO it is not mandatory. Moreover the Parent class is generally not the factory class. We can imagine a factory of complex heterogeneous class hierarchy with different parent classes and a common external factory.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok as it is, you could maybe think of making `Parent` an `abstract class` or `interface` if that fits better in your situation. But there is something in `somemethod` you could improve, either use a ternary operator as *aioobe* suggested or use a switch-case-statement, IMO they are more readable:

```
public Parent somemethod (int option)
{
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1: return Child1();
    default: return Child2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right approach, and it can be consider as [Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can store sub class object in super class reference variable. This is called as upcasting and which perfectly fine in java. And Your code seems to be perfect.